# simple question - change bits in java

Tags: java

I have a simple question - I need to write a function for my program to change the 3rd bit of a given byte.

I wrote those lines :

```
public byte turnOn(Byte value)
{
    int flag = 8;
    value = (byte) (value | flag);
    return value;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do that, because I saw also this way (with which I am unfamiliar)

```
value = (byte) (value | (1 << 2) );
```

which way is better, and what does 1 << 2 means (2 means the third bit, but what is the 1 )

Thanks!

Comment: Note that or'ing `value` with 8 (as `turnOn` does) sets the 4th bit from the right; or'ing with `(1 << 2)` sets the 3rd bit. So the two examples are not equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1 << 2` means 1 shifted two bits to the left. Since shifting left by one bit is similar to multiplying by two, this gives 4. In binary, this is

```
00000100
```

i.e. the 3rd bit from the right is set.

The constant `1` is used since that number only has a single bit set - the rightmost bit. After shifting left, only the 3rd bit (from the right) is set:

```
00000001 original value
00000010 after shifting left once
00000100 after shifting left again
```

I prefer using `1 << 2` instead of a constant like `8`, as it makes it clearer which bit is being set. It also prevents you inadvertently using a constant that has multiple bits set - unless you actually want that, of course. Even then, it's clearer in my opinion to add together several bits, for clarity:

```
final int bitsToSet = (1 << 2) + (1 << 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

4 (or 1 << 2) is `00000100` in binary¹. ORing with this mask sets the third least significant bit (or the fifth significant bit in a byte).

8 (or 1 << 3) is `00001000` in binary, so you're setting the *fourth* least significant bit (or the fifth one of a byte).

It does not matter which expression you use, the shifting just makes it clear you're using a bitmask. Alternatively, you can use the hexadecimal `0x04` which is (imho) easier to translate to the binary bitmask.

<sup>1 The leading zeros do not change the value, but should simplify counting the position of the set bit in a byte.</sup>

Comment: thank you, since I new here I can't vote up at the moment , but thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`(1 << 2)` will left-shift the value `1` twice.  Generically, `(x << y)` means `x * (2 ^ y)`.  So `1 << 2` is 4.

Generally speaking, it should not matter whether you use the bit-shift or bit-set method.  The compiler should optimize either way.

That said, are you looking for the 3rd bit, indexed from 0 or indexed from 1?  If you're looking for the third-right-most bit starting at index 1, you want your `flag` to be 4 instead of 8.  Additionally, the `|` operator is the set-value operator.  If you literally want to "change" the bit, you want to use the `^` operator -- bitwise XOR -- which is the toggle-value operator.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it's also a good explanation, sorry I can't vote up cause I'm new here, but thanks !